# Which of the database table design is better below?

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing a product table and this ideas i want to expose for your opinion.

I need to design table of products for a site and sale/discount will be on product..i have two 2 methods on my mind which one is better

**option1: the discount in the product table**

```
product table

id name price discount category
1  pen   70    0.20     2
```

**option2: the discount is in another table**

```
product table

id name   price category
1  pen     70    2
2  pencil

discount table
id discount
1  0.20

productdiscount table
prodid  discountid
 1        2
```

Comment: according to theory option 2 is much better as its normalized but it also depends on number of records and future enhancements you want to implement in future.

Comment: how about one where the price is not in the product table, and the discount is not in the discount table

Comment: Option 1 means you will give the same discount to every single customer for that product, and there will be no record of when discount changes. It will be difficult to answer how much money was made when product was discounted 20%. The topic of discount is not easy. Its a board question to answer.

Comment: there is the concept of the order and orderline tables tho, @zedfoxus, so that could care for it. But I agree, Option 1 is shabby (in my own words)

Comment: Yes, @Drew, so true. Good point. A sales_promo_header and detail table can describe discount by product and customer and apply to orders automatically for its effective dates. Order header can have a global discount applied to overall order and discounts per detail line item can also help in business analytics. It may be an overkill of a discussion for this question though.

Comment: Yep, and as for 'how much money was made', well that comes with other tables, like cost, LIFO, FIFO, acct systems, well beyond the scope here

Answer (score 3):

Depends but in your case i guess option 1 is better.

If you go with option 2 you might as well go fully mental and put the price in a different table just because you can. Ask the people that just answered option 2 and they will say that you should ....

There is such a thing as over normalization of database tables.

The only question that you need to ask yourself to choose between the 2 options is: Do I ever need to change the discount of all the products that have 10 dollars off? Should me changing the discount value to 15 reflect in all products that have that discount? Most of the time the answer is no, the discount is on an individual product base.

Comment: haha, see, somebody already told you to put the price in another table :). Normalize the hell out of it... the more tables you have the better programmer you are it looks like.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Also I may have misread your answer, were you making a joke?

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is better, generally speaking.

That is because it is easy to add multiple discounts to a single product, if that business logic ever becomes desired.

It is also possible to reuse discounts. Say you eventually have a discount table like this:

```
discount
id    type          value         expires          maxuses
1     percent       20            10-22-2015       500
2     flat          1.50          12-31-2015       null
```

You don't need to modify your product_discount table or your product table for the above to still work.

Comment: @Pratically: Thanks a lot for your answer..you even help me improve my discount table with the table you designed...but what is the use of : maxuuses column in your discount table?

Comment: I designed that based on previous work where the client desired coupons that had limited life and limited use count. Another table that associates the used discount / coupon with the specific order would be used to count total uses so far. So when the total uses passes max uses, any further use of the discount or coupon would be disabled with an appropriate message.

Comment: @wow..that is really cool...thanks..for the inspiration

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion I would choose option 2 yet different ideas. There are several reasons.

1. First, table `productdiscount` would be unnecessary as you already have `discount` table, making one more table with both ID from two tables are unnecessary unless it is many to many relationship and you have to create a bridge. Besides, you have to join three tables in order to retrieve product details and the discount value which makes it not a good practice.

2. Second, I would suggest you create a table `discountHistory`, the reason for creating this table is for checking when, who, and why change the discount. The same might go for price too. For example, create a table `priceHistory` to keep track of price changes in the past.

In summary, there should be `product`, `discount`, `discountHistory`, `priceHistory` tables, I recommend you this database table design because it is normally used in many shopping malls.

Comment: Thanks for your point..and regarding making one more table with both ID from two tables....i know what you mean...the tables i designed was only for example purposes only...thanks